# Embed Visualforce page in public website

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to embed a public page from a Force.com site in an iframe on a public website.  The page works as expected when I load it in its own tab, but doesn't load in the iframe -- instead, I get the following error:

> Refused to display 'https://DOMAIN.cs9.force.com/PREFIX/PAGE' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

[This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24792/clickjack-protection/) implies that you can turn off same-origin policy checking on Visualforce pages by disabling click-jack protection, but I have already turned off click-jack protection and am still seeing this error.

[image]

Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 16):

Force.com Sites have click-jack settings set up on a per-site basis.  You need to change yours to "Allow framing by any page (no protection)"

1. Go to Salesforce Setup > Develop > Sites
2. Click "Edit" next to your Site
3. Change the "Clickjack Protection Level"

[image]